# How to set TLS1.3 groups to use when using Python's urllib.request API?

Tags: python, openssl

The OpenSSL API for setting TLS1.3 groups is [SSL_set1_groups](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.1/man3/SSL_set1_groups.html).

Is there any way to call this API via Python's urllib.request or any other Python API -- or achieve the same via other means?

I tried using the [OpenSSL "openssl.cnf" approach to set "Groups"](https://www.openssl.org/blog/blog/2022/10/21/tls-groups-configuration/) to achieve the same and this works fine outside of Python. Within Python it does not: It seems "openssl.cnf" is read only once at Python startup but not later, e.g., when opening different URLs.

Here's the relevant snippet from "openssl.cnf"

```
[openssl_init]
ssl_conf = ssl_sect

[ssl_sect]
system_default = system_default_sect

[system_default_sect]
Groups = $ENV::DEFAULT_GROUPS
```

and here's the calling Python code:

```
...
os.environ["DEFAULT_GROUPS"]="x25519"
with urllib.request.urlopen('https://some.test.site") as response:
...
```

But this fails to activate the (TLS1.3) Group requested.

Environment used: Linux, Python3(.11.6), OpenSSL3(.1.3).